# Keep map activity updating in background

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my Android app, I have added a map activity, and I want to be able to monitor the location in background as well and keep updating location data. This data will then be used to perform on location-specific functions.

I am new to Android, so maximum help will be appreciated.
So far, I have the basic code for launching map.

```
package com.app.alviefinal.alviefinal;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap newmap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is  not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        Log.d("Map","MapCreated");
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (newmap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            newmap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (newmap != null) {
                setUpMap();
                Log.d("MAPS","Map working");
            }
            else Log.d("MAPS","not working");
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        newmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet"));

        // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        newmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Get the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Get Current Location
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // set map type
        newmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        // Get latitude of the current location
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        // Get longitude of the current location
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Show the current location in Google Map
        newmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        newmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
        newmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("My location"));

        Log.d("LATITUDE",String.valueOf(latitude));
        Log.d("LONGITUDE",String.valueOf(longitude));
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener listener = new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PrefActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }

        };

        newmap.setOnMarkerClickListener(listener);
        newmap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                // Setting the title for the marker.
                // This will be displayed on taping the marker
                markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);


                // Animating to the touched position
                newmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                newmap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                Log.d("ADDED LATITUDE",String.valueOf(latLng.latitude));
                Log.d("ADDED LONGITUDE",String.valueOf(latLng.longitude));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to perform tasks in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to get data in the background. For that you have to create a class that extends Service class and then override onStartCommand to write your own code. Something like this:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) {
...
return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

You can use timer inside onStartCommand to update your data.
You have to register your service in Android Manifest like this:

```
<service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>
```

You must remember that the service will not start automatically if the phone is restarted. You have to use Boot [Broadcast Receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to start the service.